# Reason for unintuitive UnboundLocalError behaviour 2

Tags: python, list, global-variables, scope

Following up on [Reason for unintuitive UnboundLocalError behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188944/reason-for-unintuitive-unboundlocalerror-behaviour) (I will assume you've read it). 
Consider the following Python script:

```
def f():
    # a+=1          # 1
    aa=a
    aa+=1

    # b+='b'        # 2
    bb=b
    bb+='b'

    c[0]+='c'       # 3
    c.append('c')
    cc=c
    cc.append('c')

    d['d']=5        # Update 1
    d['dd']=6       # Update 1
    dd=d            # Update 1
    dd['ddd']=7     # Update 1

    e.add('e')      # Update 2
    ee=e            # Update 2
    ee.add('e')     # Update 2

a=1
b='b'
c=['c']
d={'d':4}           # Update 1
e=set(['e'])        # Update 2
f()
print a
print b
print c
print d             # Update 1
print e             # Update 2
```

The result of the script is:

```
1
b
['cc', 'c', 'c']
{'dd': 6, 'd': 5, 'ddd': 7}
set(['e'])
```

The commented out lines (marked 1,2) are lines that would through an UnboundLocalError and the SO question I referenced explains why. However, the line marked 3 works!

By default, lists are copied by reference in Python, therefore it's understandable that c changes when cc changes. But why should Python allow c to change in the first place, if it didn't allow changes to a and b directly from the method's scope?

I don't see how the fact that by default lists are copied by reference in Python should make this design decision inconsistent.

What am I missing folks?

**UPDATES:**

- For completeness I also added the dictionary equivalent to the question above, i.e. I added the source code and marked the update with `# Update`
- For further completeness I also added the set equivalent. The set's behavior is actually surprisingly for me. I expected it to act similar to list and dictionary...

Comment: "by default lists are copied by reference"  That's false.  Everything is a reference.  But lists are mutable objects, where integers are immutable.  It would help if you update your terminology to reflect the way Python actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike strings and integers, lists in Python are *mutable* objects. This means they are designed to be changed. The line

```
c[0] += 'c'
```

is identical to saying

```
c.__setitem__(0, c.__getitem__(0) + 'c')
```

which doesn't make any change to what the name `c` is bound to. Before and after this call, `c` is the same list – it's just the *contents* of this list that have changed.

Had you said

```
c += ['c']
c = [42]
```

in the function `f()`, the same `UnboundLocalError` would have occured, because the second line makes `c` a local name, and the first line translates to

```
c = c + ['c']
```

requiring the name `c` to be already bound to something, which (in this local scope) it isn't yet.

Comment: Good examples and very clear answer. I still think it's not intuitive (especially that different changes to the list have different affects, as you demonstrated) albeit perhaps useful in many cases.

Comment: Long story short: `expr[expr]=expr` is not `name = expr`.

Comment: \@delnan - do you guys know why set acts differently than list and dict? (I've updated the question above to show the result

Comment: @Jonathan I don't see a difference in the behavior of set. In fact, my above mentioned behavior is even clearer here, because there's no syntactic element that "pretends" to be an assignment: All you do is *call a method* on the object bound to the name "e" -- you never do any kind of assignment like "e=..."

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to think about is this: what object does a (or b or c) refer to?  The line `a += 1` is changing which integer a refers to.  Integers are immutable, so when a changes from 1 to 2, it's really the same as `a = a + 1`, which is giving a an entirely new integer to refer to.

On the other hand, `c[0] += 'c'` doesn't change which list c refers to, it merely changes which string its first element refers to.  Lists are mutable, so the same list can be modified without changing its identity.