# local variable - run time error with local

Tags: python

```
x=5

def printx()
   print x
   x=10
```

running this gives unboundlocal error

but when my function is just print x i get no error..

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188944/reason-for-unintuitive-unboundlocalerror-behaviour

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281184/why-cant-i-set-a-global-variable-in-python

Comment: @Benjamin: That is true but the missing `:` is not the reason for the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/global-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assigning a value to `x` in the function is making it a local variable, therefore shadowing the global `x = 5` specified on the previous line. And on the line you're trying to print `x`, the local version of `x` hasn't been initialized yet. It is curious how doing something on a later line is influencing lines that come before it, but that's just how it works.

You don't need any special declaration to read a global variable, therefore it works without the assignment inside the function. However, if you'd rather assign `10` to the global `x` instead of making a new, local `x`, you'll have to specify `global x` inside the function.

Comment: Why are we answering duplicates?