# Python Modules (modulename referenced before assignment)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `vm.py` in the same directory as the `main()` script (`getdata.py`). In `getdata.py`, I have

```
import vm
...
x = vm.Something()
```

Then python complains

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'vm' referenced before assignment
```

Why is that? There was no error when importing.

**UPDATE**

I found that if I did

```
from vm import *
```

Instead it worked. Also for another file/module I made, a simple `import` works. I uploaded the full code to GitHub Gist https://gist.github.com/2259298

Comment: By itself, that should work.  Probably there are other references to vm in your code which you cut out in the `...` part because you didn't think they were relevant, but really they were.  See, e.g., [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188944/reason-for-unintuitive-unboundlocalerror-behaviour), or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404534/python-globals-locals-and-unboundlocalerror).

Comment: @DSM, updated post with observations and full code on gist (https://gist.github.com/2259298)

Comment: Command line arguments are never done in camel case; `--numReferences` would be typically done as `--num-references` or `--references`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside your `main` function, you had a line `vm = VirtualMemory(args['numFrames'], algo)`. The result of this is that Python recognises `vm` as a local variable inside the function, and so when you try to access `vm`, meaning the `vm` module, before having assigned a value to it locally, it complains that you haven't assigned a value to it.

The upshot of it is that you should rename either your variable `vm` or your module `vm` to something else.

(One last thing: avoid `from X import *` statements, they make debugging hard; list what you're importing explicitly. You don't want to import names like `main`, anyway.)